# how to hide submenus in jquery menu

Tags: jquery, css

i have a menu like fllowing code

Home

- Sub Item 1

  - Sub Item 1.1

    - Sub Item 1.1.1
    - Sub Item 1.1.2
  - Sub Item 1.2
  - Sub Item 1.3
  - Sub Item 1.4
  - Sub Item 1.5
  - Sub Item 1.6
  - Sub Item 1.7
- Sub Item 2
- Sub Item 3

Product Info

- Sub Item 1
- Sub Item 2

  - Sub Item 2.1
  - Sub Item 2.2
- Sub Item 3
- Sub Item 4
- Sub Item 5
- Sub Item 6
- Sub Item 7

and a css file to arrange items as verical menu, i show submenu with in jquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ss="#menu li:hover>div";
    $("div#menu li:parent").hover(function(){
        $(ss).show(500);

    });
});
```

now how i hide this submenu while mouse leave on items????
anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean somethign like this:

```
var ss = "#menu li:hover>div";
$("div#menu li:parent").hover(
    function() {
        $(ss).show(); //this is the mousein
    },
    function() {
        $(ss).hide(); //this is the mouseout
    }
);
```

Remember that hover can take two callbacks, and the second callback will be called when the mouse leaves the element.

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: thanks Bob,  but when i use $(ss).show(500);
it blinks unormaly

Comment: Right, then just modify it like so:

        $(ss).stop().show(500);
        $(ss).stop().hide(500);

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mouseleave` event

Comment: i know i should use mouseleave event , but i dont know how use that
it hide just a submenu is opened